# maximun number of orthogonality in a space

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

For n dimensional space what is the maximum number of orthogonal vectors we can have? Is there a theory can answer this question?

Comment: Yes, this can be answered. What tools do you have at your disposal?

Comment: @Alex, do you mean software tool? the software tools I have is Matlab

Comment: Oh, no, math tools. For example, do you know that an orthogonal list of vectors must be linearly independent? This gives a good guess at what the answer should be.

Comment: @Alex, without doing any math by imagine how the orthogonal vectors looks like, the maximum number will be equal to the dimension of the space. that was known to me until this day. I'm working on project and it's give me  a results that makes me to think that is not correct, So is this correct?

Comment: Indeed, in an $n$-dimensional space, a list of vectors of length greater than $n$ cannot be orthogonal.

Comment: That's only if we assume that none of the vectors are $0$.  Technically, the $0$ vector is orthogonal to every other.

Comment: Quite right, if we don't throw out the $0$ vector, it's $n+1$.